# jenkins pipeline passing variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline and I'm building my image through a docker container and it output the image tag, I want to pass that image tag to next stage, when I echo it in the next stage it prints out. but when I use it in a shell it goes empty. here is my pipeline

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
      git( url: 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git',
            credentialsId: 'xxx',
            branch: 'master')

      }
    }
    stage('Building Image') {
      steps{
         script {
         env.IMAGE_TAG = sh script: "docker run -e REPO_APP_BRANCH=master -e REPO_APP_NAME=exampleservice -e DOCKER_HUB_REPO_NAME=exampleservice --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock registry.xxxx/build", returnStdout: true

        }
      }
    }

    stage('Integration'){
      steps{
        script{
                echo "passed: ${env.IMAGE_TAG}"
          sh """
            helm upgrade exampleservice charts/exampleservice --set image.tag=${env.IMAGE_TAG}
            """
            sh "sleep 5"


        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

pipeline output

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Integration)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
passed: 
 b79c3bf-b6eec4f


[Pipeline] sh
[test101] Running shell script
+ helm upgrade exampleservice charts/exampleservice --set image.tag=
```

getting empty image tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override this by using the 'env'.

Replace your code with this one:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
      git( url: 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git',
            credentialsId: 'xxx',
            branch: 'master')

      }
    }
    stage('Building Image') {
      steps{
         script {
         env.IMAGE_TAG = sh script: "docker run -e REPO_APP_BRANCH=master -e REPO_APP_NAME=exampleservice -e DOCKER_HUB_REPO_NAME=exampleservice --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock registry.xxxx/build", returnStdout: true

        }
      }
    }

    stage('Integration'){
      steps{
        script{
                echo "passed: ${env.IMAGE_TAG}"
          sh """
            helm upgrade exampleservice charts/exampleservice\            
            --set image.tag="${env.IMAGE_TAG}"
            """
            sh "sleep 5"


        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: im still getting null value to my env.IMAGE_TAG in sh, but echo is working
i have edit my question with pipeline output

Comment: I've edited my answer. You should not put the 'env.' prefix in the 'sh' part